# Unity Scanlines Shader not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I was working on this scanlines shader but it doesn't work.
What i try to do is to set every pixel to black if the y position is a multiple of 2. but it doesn't work. Nothing is changing on the screen.
The color inversion test (by changing `return col` to `return 1 - col` works totally fine, so the shader actually affects the image. 
 
Does anyone know what's the problem? 
Thanks.

```
    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float4 position : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;
            o.position = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

            if (i.uv.y % 2 == 0)
                col -= col;
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
```

Edit: I'm using Unity 5.5.1f1 and my build setting is Standalone Windows/MacOSX/Linux.

Comment: If you want to change every pixel to black when `i.uv.y % 2`, shouldn't `col -= col;` be `col = fixed4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`?

Comment: doesn't change anything, but this might be helpful at some point in the future, so thanks anyway

Comment: i can adjust everything to the color, the problems occur when the position comes in to play. if statements also work fine.

Comment: If nothing changed from my first comment that means that `if (i.uv.y % 2 == 0)` is never true. Try to add `0` at the end of them and see what happens. `if (i.uv.y % 2.0 == 0.0)`. You can also try the `fmod` function

Comment: still nothing, but the % operator does seem to work fine. i simply can't use the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `i.uv` has values from 0 to 1. If this is a post process effect and you want window y position that is `i.uv.y * _ScreenParams.y`, or you can use `i.vertex.y`. 
 
 
Second `someFloat % 2` returns a float in the range `0..2` (see [HLSL modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509631(v=vs.85).aspx#Additive_and_Multiplicative_Operators))
so the if statement should be:

```
if (i.uv.y * _ScreenParams.y  % 2 < 1)
   col -= col;
```

But here you can use the `step` function instead.

```
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

    float ypos = i.uv.y * _ScreenParams.y;
    float ymod = ypos % 2;

    col.rgb *= step(1, ymod);

    return col;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! that actually works pretty nicely! It seems to have a conflict with the post processing stack but I might be able to solve that myself.

Comment: Yeah after adding the destination param to Graphics.Blit in my script it all worked fine.